# Are indented code under an `if` and a `def` both called blocks in Python?

Tags: python, scope, block, terminology, indentation

In Python, [keywords](http://docs.python.org/2/library/keyword.html) like `def`, `class` introduce a new [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29). Others, like `if` or `for` do not - they use the scope of the enclosing code. (The scope resolution is explained in [Short Description of the Scoping Rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/) .)

What are the proper terminology for the code lines "indented under" these two, different kind of keywords?

Example:

```
def foo():
    do_bar() # indent type 1
    do_another_bar() # indent type 1
```

Example 2:

```
if True:
    do_something() # indent type 2
    do_more_things() # indent type 2
```

Are both indent "type 1" and "type 2" called "*blocks*" of code?

Comment: The block of lines indented below a statement is called a ["suite"](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html).

Comment: I'm having a hard time actually understanding what you're asking about here.  Variables introduced in if statements and for loops are part of the local scope if that's what you're asking ...

Comment: @mgilson: I didn't mean valid variable naming. I'm trying to talk about the code block, but not sure if that's the right term. I've tried to clarify my question with an example.

Comment: @mgilson but I think the question refers to the fact that `if` and `for` do not create a new local scope, whereas `def` and `class` do.  Obviously variables introduced _anywhere_ are part of their local scope unless declared otherwise, but how big of a block that scope is in question.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, yes, any section of text indented under a `<keyword-clause>:` is called a "block".

The same is true of any section of text within curly braces in C/C++/Java/JavaScript/Perl/PHP/etc. Indentation is Python's curly-braces.

Answer (score 2):

### Compound Statements and Suites

The grammar for a [compound statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html) in Python defines the indented block of code as a "suite." For example:

```
if_stmt ::=  "if" expression ":" suite
             ( "elif" expression ":" suite )*
             ["else" ":" suite]
```

So, in a practical example like:

```
if True:
    print "It's true!"
```

the line containing the print statement (and any other lines within that level of indentation) would be a suite.

If it helps to think of each level of indentation as a code block, fine. However, the Python grammar calls it a suite. :)

Comment: I suspect not using the word "block" is to avoid confusing people familiar with block-scoped languages. Not that this helps all that much.